# Immediate invocation in node.js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any reason why I should (or should not) use immediate invocations around the code in my node.js modules?

Usually for JavaScript in the browser I would wrap all my code, like so:

```
(function() {
  var x, y;

  // etc...

}());
```

This, of course, makes it so x and y are scoped to the function and not globally scoped, but I understand that node.js has a different global scope for each module. So, should I leave out the immediate invocation code? like this:

```
var x, y;

// etc...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

In Node.JS, each module is sandboxed and has its own scope.

Comment: So you're saying I should not use immediate invocation to force sandboxing?

Comment: When you declare a global variable or a function in a module, it's not declare in the global context of your application. Juste for the module.

Comment: You can read the [documentation of module API](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for more details.

Comment: What about `use string;` for the whole file so that we are not made to add this line to every single method?

Comment: You certainly want to say `use strict`. Yes that's right. Read the [strict mode documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) for more details.